# How can playwright launch a chromium which can remember the cookie of last time?

Tags: cookies, playwright, microsoft-edge-chromium

How can playwright launch a chromium which can remember the cookie of last time?
I mean when I use Selenium, it can remember the last state and second time I don't have to handle the cookie.

Can playwright-chromium do it?

Comment: Use persistent contexts to save states and re-use them later

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse signed in state according to this:
https://playwright.dev/docs/auth